# OneNote-API opens OneNote-Application on OnenotePage.Save()

Tags: c#, onenote, onenote-api

I'm trying to extract the ocr from an image using the onenote-API.
So everything works just fine and as expected. But when I call method *save* from class *OnenotePage*, the OneNote-Application gets opened.

My code so far:

```
private const int PollInterval = 250;
private const int PollAttempts = 2;

public string RecognizeIntern(Image image)
{
    var app = new Application();
    var page = new OnenotePage(app);

    page.Reload();
    page.Clear();
    page.AddImage(image);
    page.Save()
    int total = 0;
    do
    {
        Thread.Sleep(PollInterval);
        page.Reload();
        string result = page.ReadOcrText();
        if (result != null)
            return result;
    } while (total++ < PollAttempts);

    return null;
}
```

my OnenotePage "save" method:

```
public void Save()
{
    app.GetPageContent(this._pageId, out strXml, PageInfo.piBinaryData);
    document = XDocument.Parse(strXml);
    var xml = document.ToString();
    app.UpdatePageContent(xml);

    app.NavigateTo(this._pageId);
}
```

Any idea how to save without OneNote-Application gets opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont call app.NavigateTo(this._pageId) :)